# unable to update profiles table from UsersController - cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am building a simple application in CakePHP in which users can register with data saved in the users table in my database. They also have a profile associated with the user, and I am trying to accomplish this by utilizing the $hasOne and $belongsTo association. The user hasOne profile and the profile belongs to the user.

I have created a profiles table with id, and user_id, and other fields for the profile. The user_id references the id of the profile. However, when I am trying to edit the profile information in the view, I cannot update information. I get an error that says it is trying to duplicate the 'id' which corresponds to the User id in the User table. I am writing my profile_edit function in the UsersController.php, here is the code:

```
public function profile($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;

    if (!$this->User->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid user');
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
            $this->User->Profile->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your profile has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->User->read();
    }
}
```

My Profile.php Model file:

```
 <?php
   class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Profile';
    public $belongsTo = 'User'; 
   }
   ?>
```

And my views file:

```
<div class="profiles form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Profile</legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('Profile.regulator_number');
        echo $this->Form->input('Profile.website');
        echo $this->Form->input('Profile.minimum_account');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Submit');?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('List Users', array('action' => 'index'));?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to update the profiles information for each user, whether or not they have filled anything out yet or not. NOTE: if a new user registers and does not have any Profile information yet, the submit works fine. Only update is messed up. Do I maybe need to add the user_id into the profile table as soon as a user registers, as of now a newly registered user may have information in the users table but not the profiles table.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: if u wish to update only profile then you can make form with profile only if already user create profile on register time ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $this->User->id;
```

to

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $id;
```

Here is why. It works fine on your create cuz $this->User->id will give you the last ID created in the User table.  Similar to $this->User->getLastInsertID();

On an edit you want to take the SAME id which is the one you passed as an argument initially.

Also consider adding the other options to the model i.e the other foreign keys etc to fully establish your relationship.

Example from site

```
class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className'    => 'User',
            'foreignKey'   => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: Thanks! I added this to the code, but for some reason instead of updating the row in the DB, it is creating a new row and therefore keeping the old information in the previous row. I initially used the user_id also as the primary without an additional id column. But I received an error that it was once again trying to update the primary key. I guess I need a way to update the rest of the row, but not the primary/user_id.

Comment: In cake you should use id auto_increment as the primary key.  The foreign key is different in this scenario.  if you want to use that as   a primary key you have to designate that...but as far as things go to follow convention it would be a lot smoother for you to just use id as the primary key.

You may want to check this tutorial out

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJAMifqF5s8

Look at his model structure

Also check the cake Cookbook. Usually in cake the "id" column by default is assumed as the primary key.

Comment: @user2033570 check this out 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html